# SQL - Transpose

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

i have small issues i have been trying to figure out in SQL. I have a table with Item Numbers, Attribute Names and Attribute values. Each Item Number might have same or different set of Attribute Names associated with its Attribute values. What i am trying to do is to have unique Item Number per row and transpose Attribute Names to be my columns and Attribute Values to be placed under corresponding Attribute Name header in that case.

On the image below is the current tbl_ICC table:

[image]

What I am trying to get is this view:

[image]

I read several similar posts on here and other sources and the closest i came up is this SQL query:

```
  SELECT*
  FROM
  (SELECT [ITEM_NUMBER],
      [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME],
      [ATTRIBUTE_VALUE]
  FROM  tbl_ICC) AS SourceTable
  PIVOT 
  (([ATTRIBUTE_VALUE])
  FOR   [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME] IN ( Select* [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME] FROM tbl_ICC))
  AS PivotTable;
```

For some reason i keep getting errors with syntax and the query is not giving me anything. 
What do I need to change here in order to convert the view from image1 to view on image 2?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using an image to provide data is a pain because it means inquiring minds cant then take that data and run their own tests against it for you.   Not a major biggie but slightly annoying.

Comment: I apologize for that. Is there a way i can post this small table in here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in your original query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM
  (SELECT [ITEM_NUMBER],
          [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME],
          [ATTRIBUTE_VALUE]
    FROM  tbl_ICC ) AS SourceTable 
  PIVOT (max([ATTRIBUTE_VALUE])
   FOR   [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME] IN ([color],[size] ))   -- << Add More Attr Display Name Here
  AS PivotTable;
```

> **EDIT - Dynamic Version**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME]) From tbl_ICC  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select * 
From (
       Select [ITEM_NUMBER],
              [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME],
              [ATTRIBUTE_VALUE]
        From  tbl_ICC  
     ) A
 Pivot (max(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE) For [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Comment: John - ok this gets me very close to what i want. Now since the Attribute Name is not constant per item,  I have over 1000 of them, instead of typing them as you suggested ([color],[size] )) i need this to be automatically read from [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME]. I thought if instead of using ([color],[size] ) i use ( Select* [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME] FROM tbl_ICC) that this automatically would populate it for me. Any idea if something like this could work?

Comment: @Slavisha You would need to go dynamic... one moment and I'll update my answer

Comment: @Slavisha See Updated Answer

Comment: Ok so this is actually awesome, the only problem with Dynamic Version i have is error that says: "The column 'Depth' was specified multiple times for 'p'.". I think this is happening because i have many of these Attribute names repeating for items.  length, mass etc. However since you are  using Select Distinct i dont see the reason why would duplicate the Depth. Btw you dont see Depth in the table i posted but in full data table Depth is one of the attribute names.

Comment: @Slavisha Any leading or trailing spaces ??   Perhaps ltrim(rtrim(ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME))

Comment: John, thats exactly what the issue was.  Thank you so much for all your help this is just amazing. Thank you Thank you Thank you.

Comment: John, is there a way i can insert this data in to the table after i execute this script? I tried using insert into but it keeps failing. Can i even push the variable like this to table?

Answer (score 0):

I have just done this for my own data and I found the following worked for me:

Change the following line :

```
    PIVOT 
  (([ATTRIBUTE_VALUE])
  FOR   [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME] IN ( Select* [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME] FROM tbl_ICC))
```

To:

```
PIVOT 
  (max(attribute_values) FOR   [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME] IN ( Select* [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME] FROM tbl_ICC))
```

Note I removed the Attribute_Value in the Pivot.

*note: you need to check your variable names to ensure what I have written is what you need.

Comment: - David I did what you suggested and It is telling me that i have syntax issue next to Select* and   [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME] within "IN ( Select* [ATTR_DISPLAY_NAME] FROM tbl_ICC))"

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using two tables, the first one using the item number as the primary key with color, speed, mass, etc as it's columns. The second table could then have a one to many relationship with the first table on the item number and have the attribute names and attribute values as its columns. This will not only allow you to print out the data you need (by using a join), but it will make database maintenance easier over time as things change.