# ms sql query to convert rows into columns different situation

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table like below, I tried many solutions but i didn't get success. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
   ________________________________________
   |Trend    |  MemberName  |   MemberValue|
   |---------------------------------------|
   |1/1/2017 |  TCS         |   6215812.027|
   |1/1/2017 |  InfoSys     |   2920385.747|
   |1/1/2017 |  Maruti      |   3223330.947|
   |2/1/2017 |  TCS         |   4644255.532|
   |2/1/2017 |  InfoSys     |   2378019.663|
   |2/1/2017 |  Maruti      |   2315258.732|
   |3/1/2017 |  TCS         |   4377771.365|
   |3/1/2017 |  InfoSys     |   2457987.188|
   |3/1/2017 |  Maruti      |   2060665.477|
   |4/1/2017 |  TCS         |   3749728.998|
   |4/1/2017 |  InfoSys     |   2161210.683|
   |4/1/2017 |  Maruti      |   1828319.789|
   |5/1/2017 |  TCS         |   3727746.97 |
   |5/1/2017 |  InfoSys     |   2478883.144|
   |5/1/2017 |  Maruti      |   1717573.406|
   ----------------------------------------
```

I want like this

```
   ____________________________________________________________
   |Trend       |  TCS /Top1    | InfoSys/Top2   |  Maruti/Top2|
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   |1/1/2017    |  6215812.027  |   2920385.747  |  3223330.947|
   |2/1/2017    |  4644255.532  |   2378019.663  |  2315258.732|
   |3/1/2017    |  4377771.365  |   2457987.188  |  2060665.477|
   |4/1/2017    |  3749728.998  |   2161210.683  |  1828319.789|
   |5/1/2017    |  3727746.97   |   2478883.144  |  1717573.406|
   -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Member name can be Top1, Top2, Top3 etc.
You can use given query to create table and generate sample data.

```
  CREATE TABLE Members
  (
  Trend DATE, 
  MemberName VARCHAR(20), 
  MemberValue FLOAT
  )

  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('1/1/2017','TCS',6215812.027)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('1/1/2017','InfoSys',2920385.747)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('1/1/2017','Maruti',3223330.947)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('2/1/2017','TCS',4644255.532)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('2/1/2017','InfoSys',2378019.663)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('2/1/2017','Maruti',2315258.732)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('3/1/2017','TCS',4377771.365)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('3/1/2017','InfoSys',2457987.188)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('3/1/2017','Maruti',2060665.477)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('4/1/2017','TCS',3749728.998)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('4/1/2017','InfoSys',2161210.683)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('4/1/2017','Maruti',1828319.789)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('5/1/2017','TCS',3727746.97)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('5/1/2017','InfoSys',247888.144)
  INSERT INTO Members(Trend, MemberName, MemberValue) VALUES('5/1/2017','Maruti',1717573.406)
```

Comment: MS-SQL is used.

Comment: Searching for questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484521/sql-transpose) about how to transpose table data might help you.

Comment: What do you mean by `Member name can be Top1, Top2, Top3 etc`?

Comment: @ManojPilania Waiting for what? (You are expected to to research and work at solving your own question on [SO].)

Comment: Is the combination of `Trend` and `MemberName` unique?

Comment: yes Member name can be TCS = Top1, InfoSys=Top2, Maruti=Top3 etc

Comment: So if there could be a different count of columns you have to search information about the dynamic pivot.

Comment: @Richard, In output Trend is unique and Members name as column name, can name can be replaced by Top1, Top2, Top2 etc

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas Count is fixed for columns

Comment: So, in this case, use information about regular `PIVOT`. There already are so many answers about `PIVOT`.

Comment: *I tried many solutions* - then you should be able to show one or two of those solutions you tried here, in your post. If they're not in your post, they don't exist. *But honest, teacher! I DID my homework, but my dog ate it!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use pivot.

For more detail about pivot please visit this link : [pivot tutorial](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/pivot.php)

You can use this query for the result.

```
 select * from 
 (
     select Trend, MemberName, MemberValue from Members 
 ) M
 pivot
 (
     sum(MemberValue)
     for MemberName in ([TCS], [InfoSys], [Maruti])
 ) piv;
```

Result;

```
Trend       TCS         InfoSys     Maruti
2017-01-01  6215812,027 2920385,747 3223330,947
2017-02-01  4644255,532 2378019,663 2315258,732
2017-03-01  4377771,365 2457987,188 2060665,477
2017-04-01  3749728,998 2161210,683 1828319,789
2017-05-01  3727746,97  247888,144  1717573,406
```

Hope this help to you.